# Attempting to add OpenTok 2.3 as a local cocoapod

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, opentok

I need to add OpenTok 2.3 to a project that uses cocoapods, however only 2.1.7 is present in the pods repository or on github, so I have downloaded the framework locally. My folder structure looks something like this:

```
project-
       |
       Podfile
       project.xcodeproj
       frameworks/
                 |
                 OpenTokSDK-WebRTC.podspec
                 OpenTok-iOS-2.3.0/
                                  |
                                  OpenTok.framework
```

And the contents of the OpenTokSDK-WebRTC.podspec file is:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name = 'OpenTokSDK-WebRTC'
s.version = '2.3'
s.authors = 'TokBox'
s.summary = 'The OpenTok iOS SDK lets you use OpenTok video sessions in apps you build for iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch devices.'
s.homepage = 'https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-webrtc/'
s.license = {
    :type => 'Apache'
}
s.source = {
    :path => './OpenTok-iOS-2.3.0'
}
s.platforms = {
    :ios => '5.0'
}
s.source_files = 'Opentok.framework/Versions/A/Headers/*.h'
s.resources = 'Opentok.framework/Versions/A/Resources/opentok.bundle'
s.frameworks = [
    "Opentok",
    "UIKit",
    "CoreMedia",
    "CoreVideo",
    "CoreAudio",
    "CoreTelephony",
    "CFNetwork",
    "AVFoundation",
    "SystemConfiguration",
    "Security",
    "QuartzCore",
    "AudioToolbox",
    "OpenGLES",
    "MobileCoreServices"
]
s.libraries = [
    "stdc++",
    "z"
]
s.xcconfig = {
    :FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS => "\"frameworks/OpenTokSDK-WebRTC/\""
}
s.preserve_paths = 'Opentok.framework'
s.requires_arc = false

end
```

The relevant line in the Podfile is

```
pod 'OpenTokSDK-WebRTC', :path => "frameworks"
```

When I run 'pod install' everything appears to run fine, however there is no OpenTokSDK folder in the Pods directory and I get a file not found error in xcode when trying to include . Does anyone know what I am missing?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I found on their **Blog** Here is the link [new-in-ios-10-the-best-webrtc-apps-yet](https://tokbox.com/blog/new-in-ios-10-the-best-webrtc-apps-yet/). you need to Add  `pod 'OpenTok'` in your pod file. So updated version of talk box is Added in your Project. and Now Open your **xcworkspace** file inplace of **xcodeproj** file .

Here is my Podfile ,

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'OpenTok'
  # Pods for ProjectName

  target 'ProjectNameTest' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ProjectNameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

**Note :-** If you are using Swift then please uncomment  **# use_frameworks!**

After updating your pod file enter "pod install" command in your terminal. and Tokbox will successfully install in your project.[image]

---

[image]